# retry download failed in mozilla firefox

Tags: firefox, downloads

I am trying to download the iso of backtrack 5 r3 from my mozilla firefox. It is a 3.1GB file. Due to power failure, the download stopped some times in the middle. However, I used the mozilla's retry option to resume my download. It worked for sometimes. It stopped one more time because of power failure. And then, I tried the same mozilla retry. Unfortunately, it is not working.

So far, the download is complete upto 2.9 GB. I am able to see the partially downloaded file in my download as **BT5R3-GNOME-32.iso.part**. Please help me resume my download.

---

**UPDATE 1:**

I browsed a little and I found as if there is another way of resuming failed download. I decided to go with `wget`. I tried the following command:

```
wget -c http://ftp.cc.uoc.gr/mirrors/linux/backtrack/BT5R3-GNOME-32.iso -O /home/ramvignesh/Downloads/BT5R3-GNOME-32.iso.parts
```

But it isn't working. It just starts the download right from the beginning. The download time is horrendous for me. It says the remaining download time is 4days 11hours.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### First of all make a copy backup from your `BT5R3-GNOME-32.iso.part` file, next:

Rename your copied *BT5R3-GNOME-32.iso.part* file to *BT5R3-GNOME-32.iso* and switch to Downloads directory `cd /home/ramvignesh/Downloads` which is your downloaded *BT5R3-GNOME-32.iso* file (being renamed) is there, then try to resume it by the following `wget` command:

```bsh
wget -c "http://ftp.cc.uoc.gr/mirrors/linux/backtrack/BT5R3-GNOME-32.iso"
```

**or** use below command directly after renaming it to `BT5R3-GNOME-32.iso` instead:

```bsh
wget -c "http://ftp.cc.uoc.gr/mirrors/linux/backtrack/BT5R3-GNOME-32.iso" -O /home/ramvignesh/Downloads/BT5R3-GNOME-32.iso
```

Comment: +1 for the proper use of an obscure flag like `-c`.

Answer (score 0):

Found one more solution for this.

- create a new folder (say **old part**) inside your downloads folder
- move the `.part` file to the **old part** folder created
- now open your browser and start a new download of the same file to be downloaded
- pause it after some seconds. you'll now have a fresh `.part` file inside your downloads folder
- replace it with the `.part` file inside our **old part** folder
- resume the paused download from the browser and get the download going

That's it.